# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GPIO' WebIOPi using RPI 3

Tags: gpio, pi-3, webiopi

I had this web application running from a Raspberry Pi 2 with no problem using WebIOPi, I recently acquired a Raspberry Pi 3, and I wanted to use the same application on it, using a 7'' screen.

I installed WebIOPi with no problem, and copied the same html files and the script I had in the other Pi. But when I run WebIOPi I get this error:

> File "/home/pi/myproject/python/script.py", line 8, in < module>
>       GPIO = webiopi.GPIO
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GPIO'

I saw another question that is similar, but it's for a Pi 2 and it didn't work in my case.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know the real reason of why it was acting that way, but I guess it was a compatibility problem. I solved it by patching my WebIOPi version in my Pi 3.

You can find the Github repository about it here: https://github.com/doublebind/raspi

When I patched it the problem was solved!

Now I have other problems with the WebIOPi, but that is for another question...